# Appending php array values with string doesn't give expected output

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have database query which returns an array of string values. I want them to be comma separated and appended to another string.

```
$sql1 = "select location.name as name from location,destination where destination.name='".$destination."' AND location.destination_id=destination.destination_id";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
  $insert = "";
    while($locations = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {     
  foreach ($locations as $location) {
$insert .= $location['name'] . ",";
      }
   }

$insert = rtrim($insert, ",");

 }

$sql2 = "select destination.destination_description as description from destination where destination.name='".$destination."'";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $response->speech = $destination." is the ".$row["description"].". ".$insert . "are some of the places you can try.";
   echo json_encode($response);
  }
}
```

This $insert array doesn't give the expected result. It gives just "N".

Comment: Have you tested you queries and do they return the expected results? From my view, they don't seem to be valid (at least in MYSQL).

Comment: you don't need to use foreach inside the while loop, also have a look at [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: @chade_ : yes they give the results.

Comment: @hassan : the "$locations" is inside the while loop

Comment: leave out the foreach loop, `$insert .= $locations['name'] . ",";` , you need to read about how [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) works

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the line foreach ($locations as $location)

Your while already fetch all rows to locations so you just need to append your locations[‘name’]. Your foreach has retrieved each character in the string $locations

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at explode function that might help you  [Explode function in php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem. You need to use implode() function of php.Try this:-

```
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
$ImplodeArray =array();
while($locations = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {     
    foreach ($locations as $location) {
        $ImplodeArray[] = $location['name'];
    }
}
$insert = implode(',',$ImplodeArray);
echo $insert;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: yeah check please